# Wait types with queries

Tags: sql-server, wait-types, waits

I have a query to find the wait types in which my system is suffering from.

```
WITH [Waits] AS
    (SELECT
        [wait_type],
        [wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [WaitS],
        ([wait_time_ms] - [signal_wait_time_ms]) / 1000.0 AS [ResourceS],
        [signal_wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [SignalS],
        [waiting_tasks_count] AS [WaitCount],
       100.0 * [wait_time_ms] / SUM ([wait_time_ms]) OVER() AS [Percentage],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [wait_time_ms] DESC) AS [RowNum]
    FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
    WHERE [wait_type] NOT IN (
        N'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER', N'BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR',
        N'BROKER_TASK_STOP', N'BROKER_TO_FLUSH',
        N'BROKER_TRANSMITTER', N'CHECKPOINT_QUEUE',
        N'CHKPT', N'CLR_AUTO_EVENT',
        N'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT', N'CLR_SEMAPHORE',

        -- Maybe uncomment these four if you have mirroring issues
        N'DBMIRROR_DBM_EVENT', N'DBMIRROR_EVENTS_QUEUE',
        N'DBMIRROR_WORKER_QUEUE', N'DBMIRRORING_CMD',

        N'DIRTY_PAGE_POLL', N'DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE',
        N'EXECSYNC', N'FSAGENT',
        N'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT', N'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX',

        -- Maybe uncomment these six if you have AG issues
        N'HADR_CLUSAPI_CALL', N'HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION',
        N'HADR_LOGCAPTURE_WAIT', N'HADR_NOTIFICATION_DEQUEUE',
        N'HADR_TIMER_TASK', N'HADR_WORK_QUEUE',

        N'KSOURCE_WAKEUP', N'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP',
        N'LOGMGR_QUEUE', N'MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT',
        N'ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE',
        N'PREEMPTIVE_XE_GETTARGETSTATE',
        N'PWAIT_ALL_COMPONENTS_INITIALIZED',
        N'PWAIT_DIRECTLOGCONSUMER_GETNEXT',
        N'QDS_PERSIST_TASK_MAIN_LOOP_SLEEP', N'QDS_ASYNC_QUEUE',
        N'QDS_CLEANUP_STALE_QUERIES_TASK_MAIN_LOOP_SLEEP',
        N'QDS_SHUTDOWN_QUEUE', N'REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK',
        N'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH', N'RESOURCE_QUEUE',
        N'SERVER_IDLE_CHECK', N'SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH',
        N'SLEEP_DBSTARTUP', N'SLEEP_DCOMSTARTUP',
        N'SLEEP_MASTERDBREADY', N'SLEEP_MASTERMDREADY',
        N'SLEEP_MASTERUPGRADED', N'SLEEP_MSDBSTARTUP',
        N'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK', N'SLEEP_TASK',
        N'SLEEP_TEMPDBSTARTUP', N'SNI_HTTP_ACCEPT',
        N'SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP', N'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH',
        N'SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP',
        N'SQLTRACE_WAIT_ENTRIES', N'WAIT_FOR_RESULTS',
        N'WAITFOR', N'WAITFOR_TASKSHUTDOWN',
        N'WAIT_XTP_RECOVERY',
        N'WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT', N'WAIT_XTP_OFFLINE_CKPT_NEW_LOG',
        N'WAIT_XTP_CKPT_CLOSE', N'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN',
        N'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT', N'XE_TIMER_EVENT')
    AND [waiting_tasks_count] > 0
    )
SELECT
    MAX ([W1].[wait_type]) AS [WaitType],
    CAST (MAX ([W1].[WaitS]) AS DECIMAL (16,2)) AS [Wait_S],
    CAST (MAX ([W1].[ResourceS]) AS DECIMAL (16,2)) AS [Resource_S],
    CAST (MAX ([W1].[SignalS]) AS DECIMAL (16,2)) AS [Signal_S],
    MAX ([W1].[WaitCount]) AS [WaitCount],
    CAST (MAX ([W1].[Percentage]) AS DECIMAL (5,2)) AS [Percentage],
    CAST ((MAX ([W1].[WaitS]) / MAX ([W1].[WaitCount])) AS DECIMAL (16,4)) AS [AvgWait_S],
    CAST ((MAX ([W1].[ResourceS]) / MAX ([W1].[WaitCount])) AS DECIMAL (16,4)) AS [AvgRes_S],
    CAST ((MAX ([W1].[SignalS]) / MAX ([W1].[WaitCount])) AS DECIMAL (16,4)) AS [AvgSig_S],
    CAST ('https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/' + MAX ([W1].[wait_type]) as XML) AS [Help/Info URL]
FROM [Waits] AS [W1]
INNER JOIN [Waits] AS [W2]
    ON [W2].[RowNum] <= [W1].[RowNum]
GROUP BY [W1].[RowNum]
HAVING SUM ([W2].[Percentage]) - MAX( [W1].[Percentage] ) < 95; -- percentage threshold
GO
```

Query is taken from Paul Randal's blog [Wait statistics, or please tell me where it hurts](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/)

Now is there a way I can correlate the wait types with my actual queries. After some research I found we can configure extended events to capture the query with wait types.

Is there any other alternative through any DMV's can we get wait types along with queries.

Answer (score 4):

You could either use Adam Mechanics [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) or the below script and periodically insert the results into a table for later analysis.

Brent Ozar has a [good post](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) on how to do this is you decide you use sp_whoisactive

```
    SELECT
    [owt].[session_id],
    [owt].[exec_context_id],
    [owt].[wait_duration_ms],
    [owt].[wait_type],
    [owt].[blocking_session_id],
    [owt].[resource_description],
    CASE [owt].[wait_type]
        WHEN N'CXPACKET' THEN
            RIGHT ([owt].[resource_description],
            CHARINDEX (N'=', REVERSE ([owt].[resource_description])) - 1)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [Node ID],
    [es].[program_name],
    [est].text,
    [er].[database_id],
    [eqp].[query_plan],
    [er].[cpu_time]
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks [owt]
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions [es] ON
    [owt].[session_id] = [es].[session_id]
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests [er] ON
    [es].[session_id] = [er].[session_id]
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text ([er].[sql_handle]) [est]
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan ([er].[plan_handle]) [eqp]
WHERE
    [es].[is_user_process] = 1
ORDER BY
    [owt].[session_id],
    [owt].[exec_context_id];
GO
```

For you info dm_os_waiting_tasks are what is **currently** happening on your sql server, dm_os_wait_stats are what has happened in the past/or since you restarted sql or it's services.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you can use a new dynamic management view, or DMV, to see wait stats by session, for currently connected sessions:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats desws
WHERE desws.session_id = <session_id>;
```

Replace `<session_id>` with the SPID you're interested in.

The output contains a row for each wait type, along with the number of tasks that waited, and the amount of time they waited.